# DB2 - Declare Cursor in Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, cursor, db2, db2-luw

I've found this "DECLARE CURSOR" Statement on WWW:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "APART21C"."FIND_VALID_ARZTNRN"
(OUT NoOfRows BIGINT)
RESULT SETS 1
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC SQL140905135133600
BEGIN
  
  DECLARE myARZTNR CHAR(7);
  DECLARE END_TABLE INT DEFAULT 0
  ;
  DELETE FROM APART21C.TMP_LANR07_CHECK
  ;
  DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
  SELECT DISTINCT Arztnr 
  FROM APART21C.DMP_LEV_TMP
  ;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
   SET END_TABLE = 1
  ;
  OPEN C1
  ;
  FETCH C1 INTO myARZTNR
  ;
  WHILE END_TABLE = 0 DO
  
        INSERT INTO APART21C.TMP_LANR07_CHECK
        SELECT * FROM TABLE(APART21C.CHECK_ARZTNR_BY_CHECKSUM(myARZTNR)) AS ARZTNRCHECK;
        SET NoOfRows = NoOfRows + 1;
        
        FETCH C1 INTO myARZTNR;
                
  END WHILE
  ;
  CLOSE C1
  ;
END
```

Errormessage is

```
"DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=<cursor declaration>;;<SQL statement>"
```

Need your help, please

I'm a beginner of db2, I've more experience in MS SQL Server.
The statement "`SELECT * FROM TABLE(...`" calls a function which returns a table.

Comment: All `DECLARE` statements in compound SQL must appear _before_ any executable statements, such as `DELETE`. Search for "compound SQL" in the manual for your version of DB2.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: **@user2338816**: The question is _WHY THIS ERROR IS DISPLAYED?_ (It's easy to divine :)

Comment: **@mustaccio**: Error disappeared, I too. Thank you for your fast help :)

Comment: Do you even need the cursor?  Why not just do the select as part of the insert?  The way you're doing it is going to eat extra overhead, for no real benefit.

Comment: Only for excercise.

I hoped to learn more about db2 syntax 

Greets from Bavaria, where today is the last day of "Oktoberfest" :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the below code

DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
  SELECT DISTINCT Arztnr 
  FROM APART21C.DMP_LEV_TMP

I have changed as below and it executed

DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
  SELECT Arztnr FROM DMP_LEV_TMP;